# Drive not mounting in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mount

I get this error message when I'm trying to mount my Windows' drives through a file manager which would otherwise mount the partitions automatically.
How to fix this?

```
                Unable to access “New Volume”

Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/archisman/New Volume:
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/
media/archisman/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: 
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I am a Linux newbiw and hence I do not know about the more technical details of the situation. Please help. Plus, I have repeatedly shut down my Windows 8.1 properly without hibernating it or anything.

PS.- I'm using the Gnome Desktop Environment, if it is of any concern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: If you are dual booting, you can reboot into Windows and it should fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the following command , get info about your drives

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

Then mount the drives using following command

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

Here sda1 i used as example , replace sda1 with corresponding sda number ,command 1 gives the sda number of your drive

and remember windows drives are of ntfs partition

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. And will I have to do it everytime I boot my system? And why did this happen? It wasn't always like this.

Comment: thank you so much, worked for me too